# Virtual destructor for pure abstract base classes

Tags: c++, g++, abstract-class, clang++, virtual-destructor

I have seen [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284561/when-not-to-use-virtual-destructors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) that a good rule of thumb is to use virtual destructors for every class that is intended as a base class. I have a pure abstract base class (only contains pure virtual functions and no data members; intended to be used as an interface).

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Is it possible to add a virtual destructor to this class without creating an implementation file (this class is defined in a header file included in several .cpp files) just for an empty destructor while also avoiding clang and g++ warnings such as -Wweak-vtables?  I cannot put the empty definition in the header file with the pure abstract class because I will get multiple definitions of the destructor.

Comment: " will get multiple definitions of the destructor."  - no, you won't, if it is inline in the class - have you tried?

Comment: `virtual ~A() = default;`

Comment: Or `virtual ~A() {}`

Comment: @Neil Butterworth This triggers the -Wweak-vtables from clang

Comment: Hm, I think that duplicate is a different question.

Comment: Well, that's a problem with clang - it is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: @user4581301 That answered my question! Thank you!

Comment: [What is the meaning of clang's -Wweak-vtables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746941/what-is-the-meaning-of-clangs-wweak-vtables)

Comment: @juanchopanza This is a different question from that one since the answer to that question triggers the -Wweak-vtables from clang

Comment: @AdamSperry That was unclear from your question.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c. Doesn't error with clang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas, clang generates warning for:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

using `= default` doesn't trigger it.

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Even if both are valid.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7cac8dc187e3c9)